# junit - Cucumber Runner class access a common method before executing tests

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

I have 3 cucumber junit runner class executing all the test cases in parallel. I am using maven-surefire-plugin to run all the runner classes in parallel. I want to setup some data which is common to all the 3 test runners which are running in parallel, Are there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

@user2391218 You can maintain the the common data in a property/yml file.